# About LFTP and SFTP

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, ssl, sftp

Hi I only know about simple FTP command, but I came to know simple command is not that secure, so i had my reseach about FTP and came across below syntax, but I cannot get what it is doing so, can anyone please give detail explanation.

1) what is the diff between `lftp -u ${recs_ftp_user}` and `lftp -u $recs_ftp_user`?
2)what does sftp and debug command is doing?
3)what is `ftp:ssl-force` and what happens when it is set to TRUE or FALSE?

```
lftp -u ${recs_ftp_user},${recs_ftp_pass} sftp://${ftp_ip}<<EOF
debug -o "$ftp_log_ftp2"
set ftp:ssl-force true
set net:max-retries 4
cd "$retrieve_dir"
lcd "$MY_NAS"
get "$input_data"
get -a "$input_index"
bye
EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the diff between `lftp -u ${recs_ftp_user}` and `lftp -u $recs_ftp_user`

That's not really an FTP question, and not an lftp question either.

$variables are processed by your *shell* (i.e. the command interpreter) before actually running the 'lftp' command. There are several ways to specify a variable, and in your case both are completely identical.

The difference only becomes visible when you have a variable expansion immediately adjacent to other text. For example, if you had `user=fred`, then e.g. `$user_backup` would fail and think you want the variable 'user_backup' instead, but `${user}_backup` would correctly expand to 'fred_backup'.

> what does sftp and debug command is doing?

The lftp `debug` command tells it to show more details about the actual server conversation (i.e. the raw FTP or SFTP protocol messages).

> what is ftp:ssl-force and what happens when it is set to TRUE or FALSE?

It enables FTP over TLS/SSL, commonly known as "FTPS".

It has no effect on SFTP connections. (Actually *none* of the `ftp:*` settings affect SFTP.)

(FTPS runs over TLS/SSL and is still based on the same FTP otherwise, whereas SFTP runs over SSH and is a completely different protocol overall. Do not confuse the two!)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. may I also know what `SFTP` and `lcd` is doing in the code? Because i used `lftp -u $user $pwd $ftp_ip` know it has been in sftp `sftp://${ftp_ip}`.   Thank you again.